# Is it possible to turn a game made on Twine into a mobile app?

Tags: mobile, game-development, twine

I am currently working on an interactive video-game on Twine, I'm a complete beginner to this regards.

Once my game is made, that I have the full HTML and CSS file of the project, do you think it's possible to publish it on the appstore and playstore ? Because this my end-goal.

I don't want to spend a lot of time on a tool and realise once I've done everything that the game is not playable on mobile.

Thanks